# Fixed header, footer with scrollable content

Tags: html, css

How can I get fixed header, footer with scrollable content? Something like this [page](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/fixit.html). I can look at the source to get the CSS, but I just want to know minimum CSS and HTML I need to get this working.

[image]

Comment: same question with these qualifiers: angular, materialize ...

Comment: same question but with a sidebar AND where the footer doesn't appear until you chain scroll down AND you don't end up with two scrollbars on the right hand side

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Something like this

```
<html>
  <body style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div id="header" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:200px; right:0px;overflow:hidden;"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute; top:200px; bottom:200px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:auto;"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; height:200px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:hidden;"> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not related to the downvotes, but I got here and this didn't work for me (and I did copy the style literally). Probably jQuery Mobile is messing around. But even if it worked, I don't like to harcode the fixed dimensions. I guess HTML/css is a step behind from native UI components. In every native platform I've worked with, making scrollable containers was a piece of cake.

Comment: @MisterSmith  Sorry I clearly forgot to add the style to lock the right side of the containers.  In addition this code will only render to the size of its container.  If it is under the body tag and you want a full screen then you need to set height and width to 100%.  Finally as for the hard coded styles, this is only an example and not for production release, I no way would I ever release inline styles like this but it seemed a more appropriate way to explain the answer.

Comment: @JohnHartsock Definitely it was JQM doing bad things. As for the hardcoded dimensions, what I don't like is to set the absolute height in pixels. In other platforms I've worked with, it was possible to create a container and tell it to use all the height it needs.

Comment: @Mister Smith.  You do not need to hard code the dimensions in px.  You can use percentages if you would like, in addition you do not need to set the style via the style attribute on the tag, but instead just set up a css style sheet referencing the ids.  I simply did things this way in the answer to make it very easy to understand.

Comment: @JohnHartsock downvotes probably because it's inline css and doesn't explain the why's it's just a copy and paste answer

Answer (score 99):

If you're targeting browsers supporting flexible boxes you could do the following:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 2em;
}

footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  
  <div class="body">Body</div>
  
  <footer>
    <h3>Footer</h3>
  </footer>
</div>
```

See "Can I use" for [browser support of flexible boxes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: I'm using a header and footer that have a variable height and I believe this will do the trick for me. I'm also targeting the latest browsers luckily. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Is there a way to put another such construct into the `.body` area? When I do that, the outer `.container` scrolls out of the view as soon as the inner `.body .body` is scrolled all the way down.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion and this should be the best answer! Thank you!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is the answer to a different question? Here the scrollbar appears on the whole page, whereas in the answer by John the scrollbar just appears on the main content (which is what the question asks)? At least that's what I'm seeing in the fiddle.

Comment: The best answer! And only working solution I found after 1 hour of searching.

Comment: This is the best answer by far.
No need to use hacky absolute positioning!

Answer (score 75):

### Approach 1 - flexbox

It works great for both known and unknown height elements. Make sure to set the outer div to `height: 100%;` and reset the default `margin` on `body`. See the [browser support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kh20Lsz/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header, .footer {
  background: silver;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div style="height:1000px;">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

### Approach 2 - CSS table

For both known and unknown height elements. It also works in legacy browsers including IE8.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6x6t02ke/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.header, .content, .footer {
  display: table-row;
}
.header, .footer {
  background: silver;
}
.inner {
  display: table-cell;
}
.content .inner {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}
.scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner">Header</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="scrollable">
        <div style="height:1000px;">Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="inner">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Approach 3 - `calc()`

If header and footer are fixed height, you can use CSS [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ao8jqabh/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.header, .footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: silver;
}
.content {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div style="height:1000px;">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

### Approach 4 - % for all

If the header and footer are known height, and they are also percentage you can just do the simple math making them together of 100% height.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
.header, .footer {
  height: 10%;
  background: silver;
}
.content {
  height: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div style="height:1000px;">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqhj2s3p/)**

Comment: This only works if it's is a direct child of `body` with no other elements above it.  How can this work with other content above it?

Comment: You will need to use height: 100vh or set height: 100% to all parents including body and html for any container that is not directly in body

Answer (score 15):

Now we've got CSS grid. Welcome to 2019.

```css
/* Required */
body {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
   height: 100vh;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 30px 1fr 30px;
}

#content {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Optional */
#wrapper > * {
   padding: 5px;
}

#header {
   background-color: #ff0000ff;
}

#content {
   background-color: #00ff00ff;
}

#footer {
   background-color: #0000ffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">Header Content</div>
      <div id="content">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
      <div id="footer">Footer Content</div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't need the body height. Just set the wrapper height to 100vh, and it will work both here and on the wild.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2013: This would be my approach.
[jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/YBsUh/)

HTML

```
<header class="container global-header">
    <h1>Header (fixed)</h1>
</header>

<div class="container main-content">
    <div class="inner-w">
        <h1>Main Content</h1>
    </div><!-- .inner-w -->
</div> <!-- .main-content -->

<footer class="container global-footer">
    <h3>Footer (fixed)</h3>
</footer>
```

SCSS

```
// User reset

* { // creates a natural box model layout
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
} // asume normalize.css


// structure

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
}


// type

body {
    font-family: arial;   
}

.main-content {
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: .2em;
    }
} // .main-content


// style

    // variables
    $global-header-height: 8em;
    $global-footer-height: 6em;

.global-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    height: $global-header-height;
}

.main-content {
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top: $global-header-height;
    margin-bottom: $global-footer-height;
    z-index: -1; // so header will be on top
    min-height: 50em; // to make it long so you can see the scrolling
}

.global-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: $global-footer-height;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: I would likely use flex-box as of 2016. It always depends on the context though. Tricky situations! : )

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me. I had to add a margin-bottom so the footer wouldn't eat up my content:

```
header {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #1d0d0a;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hide;
}

content {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hide;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me using a CSS grid. Initially fix the container and then give   `overflow-y: auto;` for the centre content which has to get scrolled i.e other than header and footer.

```css
.container{
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 5em auto 3em;
}

header{
   grid-row: 1;  
    background-color: rgb(148, 142, 142);
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.body{
  grid-row: 2;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

footer{
   grid-row: 3;
   
    background: rgb(110, 112, 112);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header><h1>Header</h1></header>
    <div class="body">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    <footer><h3>Footer</h3></footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is a little different solution then meyertee, This worked, It keeps header and footer fixed and content scrollable. app-header is basically your header code, router-outlet is your content and app-footer is where your footer code will go.
html file

```
<div class="container">
  <app-header></app-header>
  
  <div class="body"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
  
  <footer>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

CSS File

```
.container {
    width: 100lh;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  
  header {
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
  
  .body {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 2em;
  }
  
  footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
```