# full height div to screen size - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a page where I am calculating the height of header and footer height and window height, and applying the remaining height to content area so the content area covers the and fill it.

It's not working as expected, I am getting scroll on the page which usually shouldn't be, scroll should appear only when the content of the body is more than to the remaining space.

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2208ja2/1/)

```js
function contentHeight() {
            var winH = $(window).height(),
                headerHei = $("header").height(),
                footerHei = $("footer").height(),
                contentHei = winH - headerHei - footerHei;
            $(".content-wrapper").css("min-height", contentHei);
}
        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            contentHeight();
        });
        $(window).resize(function () {
            contentHeight();
        });
```

```css
*, ::after, ::before {
 box-sizing: border-box
}
header{float:left; width:100%; padding;10px 0; background:#ececec;}
.content-wrapper{float:left; width:100%; padding:20px; background:#cdcdcd;}
footer{float:left; width:100%; padding:15px 0;  background:#333333;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header><p>This is heading</p><p>This is sub-heading</p></header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <p>
    this is content area
    </p>
    <p>
    this is content area
    </p>
    </div>
    <footer><p>This is footer</p></footer>
```

EDIT: Screenshot of chrome

Comment: Must you use jQuery?  Here is a pure css example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069734/fixed-header-footer-with-scrollable-content/4069794#4069794

Comment: I am trying to handle using JQuery only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your issue is you have used `.height()` to measure height of the element, but they have top and bottom padding and `.height()` don't consider padding. You should try `.outerHeight()`. Try this code.

```
function contentHeight() {
  var winH = $(window).outerHeight(),
    headerHei = $("header").outerHeight(),
    footerHei = $("footer").outerHeight(),
    contentHei = winH - headerHei - footerHei;
  $(".content-wrapper").css("min-height", contentHei);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  contentHeight();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  contentHeight();
});
```

You can also consider the reference for `.height` and `.outerHeight` here.
https://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/jquery-whats-the-difference-between-height-innerheight-and-outerheight

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried with the outerHeight, but still, I see scrolling on the page, how to avoid scrolling and make the page fit.

Comment: thats weird, because i tested in my system with outerHeight and it works fine and there is no scrollbar. Could you try with outerHeight(true), see if this works

Comment: tried with the `outerHeight(true)` but no change, here is the updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/u2208ja2/2/

Comment: did you try adding `margin: 0; padding: 0` to your `*` selector?

Comment: Yes, and I just noticed, Firefox is fine though, Chrome is not showing fine.

Comment: screenshot of your Chrome?

Comment: Uploaded the screenshot of chrome, you can see the footer is moving out of the screen.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar you should reset body margin = 0 in your example https://jsfiddle.net/u2208ja2/3/

Comment: i guess your screenshot is different than the code you mentioned. could you include your full code, html, css and js.

Comment: Resetting the margin body fixed the problem. thanks!

Comment: LOL...happy coding

Answer (score 1):

probably a simple:

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
```

could fix everything.

**OR**

Well, as it seems to be not calculating very well, you can try to 'bypass' this problem getting the paddings (that seems to be the problem over here).
Then you can set the content height beign:
 **total height - (footer + header + paddings)**

My code below do this, see if this helps you. (open snippet in full page size)

```js
function contentHeight() {
            var winH = $(window).outerHeight(true),
                headerHei = $("header").outerHeight(true),
                headerPad = $("header").css('padding-top').replace('px',''),
                footerHei = $("footer").outerHeight(true),
                footerPad = $("footer").css('padding-top').replace('px',''),
                paddings = parseInt(footerPad) + parseInt(headerPad),
                contentHei = winH - (headerHei + footerHei + paddings);  
            $(".content-wrapper").css("min-height", contentHei);
}
        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            contentHeight();
        });
        $(window).resize(function () {
            contentHeight();
        });
```

```css
*, ::after, ::before {
 box-sizing: border-box
}
header{float:left; width:100%; padding;10px 0; background:#ececec;}
.content-wrapper{float:left; width:100%; padding:20px; background:#cdcdcd;}
footer{float:left; width:100%; padding:15px 0;  background:#333333;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header><p>This is heading</p><p>This is sub-heading</p></header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <p>
    this is content area
    </p>
    <p>
    this is content area
    </p>
    </div>
    <footer><p>This is footer</p></footer>
```

Comment: Nice! If possible, mark it as accepted answer then, it can help another users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with it is that neither header nor footer has height.

CSS

```
*, ::after, ::before {
box-sizing: border-box
}
header{float:left; position:relative;width:100%;height:30%;top:0;left:0; padding;10px 0; background:#ececec;}
.content-wrapper{float:left; width:100%;padding:20px; background:#cdcdcd;}
footer{float:left; position:relative;width:100%;height:30%;bottom:0;left:0; padding:15px 0;  background:#333333;}

.wrapper{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

JS

```
function contentHeight() {
            var winH = $(window).height(),
                headerHei = $("header").height(),
                footerHei = $("footer").height(),
                contentHei = winH - (headerHei + footerHei);
            $(".content-wrapper").css("height", contentHei - 50 + 'px');
} 
$(document).ready(function () {
            contentHeight();
        });
        $(window).resize(function () {
            contentHeight();
        });
```

Already tested in the provided fiddler. It worked

Edit:Forgot to mention that I did not used Jquery, I do not know if it is necessary for you to use it.

Comment: I don't want to apply fixed height to header or footer, thats why I am calculating height using JS, Why JS is not working expected?

Comment: Because, it might be for the height. If you can tell me your aproach that you are attemping to reproduce it will be helpful

Comment: I modified the code, I think the padding was adding extra space to you content. But if you removed either from your css or manually when adding the height to the content will work.

Comment: Thanks for your attention on this, but I don't understand why we are reducing 50 pixel additionallly?