# Scrollable router outlet in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

My page is pretty simple. I want a fixed header and footer regardless of the screen size, and want only the content to be scrolled if it is more(if the content overflows).

```
<div class="header">
 <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <h2>footer</h2>
</div>
```

I am trying something like this and the exact below code is not working.

[Fixed header, footer with scrollable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069734/fixed-header-footer-with-scrollable-content)

Comment: have you tried flexbox?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Flexbox Layout (Flexible Box) module to align and distribute space among header, content and footer.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
  </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>footer</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

we are using an outer element with class=container to apply the display:flex and flex-direction: column properties.

In our CSS we are going to use flex-shrink and flex-grow to distribute the inner elements.

**flex-shrink**
Defines how much a flexbox item should shrink if there's not enough space available.

**flex-grow**
Defines how much a flexbox item should grow if there's space available.

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header{
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.content{
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer{
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

Finally it is important to set height 100% to HTML, body and container elements

```
html, body{
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

StackBlitz example with angular and flexbox:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fixed-footer-header

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using flexbox do the holy grail ordering of your content between your header and footer.

```css
html,
body,
.page {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content {
  background: lightskyblue;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    lorem ipsum 
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> ||<br /> ||<br />v<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> much contendo
   
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>footer</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use the same code here and still footer is not sticky to bottom and scrollbar appears just like any website

Comment: Is the footer not sticky when running the code snippet?

Comment: Yes its sticky while running your snippet, but the same code in my application is not sticky

Comment: We will need some more context to know whats is wrong there, if my code snippet works, it's probably because you are wrapping the code in some html, and you need to handle the wrapping elements size correctly.

Comment: Agree to that. I am only using your code and behaving different. I need to find out what is causing odd behavior

Comment: the initial css 
`html,
body,
.page {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}`
hints to where there are something that needs to be done, if you have some elements in between there, you need to handle it.