# Dialog with a fixed footer

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a dialog with some items ("tags") and a footer with a "done" button. When the items get populated enough, scroll is added and the footer is shown BENEATH all the items.

But I want to show the footer at all times, to be fixed, and make the scroll only work for the populated items.

```
        <Dialog
            hidden={this.state.hideDialog}
            onDismiss={this._closeWithoutSavingDialog}
            containerClassName={'ms-dialogMainOverride ' + styles.textDialog}
            modalProps={{
                isBlocking: false,
            }}>

            <div className={styles.tags}>
                <div className={styles.tagsDialogCloud}>
                    {this.state.dialogTags.map((tag, index) => this.renderDialogTags(tag, index))}
                </div>                
            </div>

            <DialogFooter>
            {this.state.showDialogButton == true ?
                <DefaultButton
                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#ff0033', color: '#ffffff' }}
                    onClick={this._closeDialog}
                    text="Done"
                />:null
            };
            </DialogFooter>
        </Dialog>
    </div>;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjB2V.png)

Picture shows an example of what I want to achieve. The "tags" part is scrollable, but the "Done" button is always shown.

Comment: Can you share more details like components & styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like a CSS problem than a React one.
The problem with your code is that the `DialogFooter` component should be absolute so it won't extend the parent's height and you should render the button without a condition.

Here's an example of how you can achieve it:
JSX:

```
<div className="popup-wrapper">
    <div className="popup">
      <div className="popup-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
        aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
        culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
      <div className="popup-footer" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.popup-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.popup {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-footer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: silver;
}

.popup-content {
  max-height: 260px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

And a sandbox can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/7y7qw60xz6?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML as your dialog code/you can modify the code as per your dialog this is a code to give you a hint.

```
<div id="header" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; height:200px; right:0px;overflow:hidden;"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute; top:200px; bottom:200px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:auto;"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; height:200px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:hidden;"> 
    </div>
```

Hope this helps...

Happy coding...

Comment: details you can get it here.. Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069734/fixed-header-footer-with-scrollable-content/21168136