# CSS Layout: Fixed header/footer and sub-header within content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a web application and want to have the following layout:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  --header--
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  --body--
  <div class="content">
     --header within body--
     <div class="sub-header">
     </div>
     ---scrollable content-
     <div class="scrollable-content">
     </div> 
  </div>
  --footer--
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>

--css---
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100vh;
}

.header {
 flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content {
 overflow-y:scroll;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

I want to assign the remaining height with scroll to "scrollable-content" div. I have come across answers where the entire content is scrollable, but that's not the case here.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: can we see your css code? have you tried overflow auto in your scrollable-content and fixed height?

Comment: take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069734/fixed-header-footer-with-scrollable-content

Comment: @Sfili_81, please check the updated css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have used shorthand css property `flex` to determine height of each `<div>` and set the `overflow: scroll;`. Hence other elements doesn't scroll on overflow of that element.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px red solid;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}

.header {
  border: 1px red solid;
  flex: 0.2;
}

.content {
  border: 1px red solid;
  flex: 0.6;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}

.sub-header {
  border: 1px red solid;
  flex: 0.15;
}

.scrollable-content {
  border: 1px red solid;
  flex: 0.85;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.footer {
  border: 1px red solid;
  flex: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    --header--
  </div>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="sub-header">
      --header within body--
    </div>

    <div class="scrollable-content">
      ---scrollable content--<br> ---scrollable content--<br> ---scrollable content--<br> ---scrollable content--<br> ---scrollable content--<br> ---scrollable content--<br> ---scrollable content--<br> ---scrollable content--<br> ---scrollable content--<br>      ---scrollable content--<br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    --footer--
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the scroll only in the scrollable-content. I found that there are two scrolls from your snippet. can you please check that?

Comment: The outer scroll is from stackoverflow as I have fixed height of `.wrapper` which is greater than the results display area. If you just put the code where you want and set `height: 100%;` to the `.wrapper`, it will just work fine.

Comment: @Jayakrishnan you want scroll only without contents